# vba launcher workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, launcher

I have a "launcher" workbook, with a userform with buttons. Each button, open an "x" workbook. Which autoexecute a macro when it's open (`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`), but, if I close the "launcher" workbook in any macro on this "x"  workbook, stop the macro.

Example: Code in the userform of "Launcher"

```
Private Sub PRG01_Click()  
Unload launcher 'my userform  
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyMacros1.xlsm"  
ThisWorkbook.Close False  
End Sub  

Private Sub PRG02_Click()  
Unload launcher 'my userform  
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyMacros2.xlsm"  
ThisWorkbook.Close False  
End Sub
```

.........................................................................
Code in MyMacros1.xlsm

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
Workbooks("Launcher.xlsm").close false' Here Macro Stop  
Call importe 'then, this code not run...  
End Sub
```

I want to close the launcher and follow the execution of macro... What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not move the `close` call until after the `Call importe`?

Comment: In any place, stop the macros, in any workbooks. Its a problem with the stack, I think.

Comment: I'm thinking in a script in VBS, perhaps, it could close the launcher and run the second worbook...

Comment: You could alternatively place the macros in the Personal.xlsb and call from there, no?

Comment: All this macros run in many share folders of a server. Its code its many complex for me!. But, VBS until now, its working! When the operator click a button, I generate and save a code. Its close the "launcher" and excute the autorun macro in another workbook!.